# Sencha Touch 2.4 : how to add multiple records to TreeStore programatically

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm having troubles with understanding of how to programatically add data to an already initialized TreeStore.

Consider the example from Sencha Touch docs:

```
  var data = {
      "items" : [{
            "text" : "Today",
            "items" : [{
                        "text" : "Eat",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "text" : "Sleep",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "text" : "Drinking",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }]
        }, {
            "text" : "Tomorrow",
            "items" : [{
                        "text" : "Watch TV",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "text" : "Watch Video",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }]
        }, {
            "text" : "This week",
            "items" : [{
                        "text" : "Shopping",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }]
        }, {
            "text" : "Later",
            "items" : [{
                        "text" : "Eat",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "text" : "Sleep",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "text" : "Drinking",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }]
        }]
   };

   Ext.define('Task', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       config: {
           fields: [{
               name: 'text',
               type: 'string'
           }]
       }
   });

   var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
       model: 'Task',
       defaultRootProperty: 'items',
       //root: data
   });

   store.addData(data.items);  // I need to add data here

   console.log(store.getAllCount()) // prints 4 but should be 13
```

As a result I get only 4 parent items added. No children are added.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `children` instead of `items`

Answer (score 0):

You only add the first level of your tree. ExtJS is looking for **children** to make his tree internally.

Change all your `items` by `children` in your JSON:

```
var data = {
      "items" : [{
            "text" : "Today",
            "children" : [{                 // <<== HERE
                        "text" : "Eat",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "text" : "Sleep",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "text" : "Drinking",
                        "leaf" : true
                    }]
        }, {
            "text" : "Tomorrow",
            "children" : [{               // <<== AND HERE

            // etc, ...
```

Comment: If you have a look at my code more attentively you will notice defaultRootProperty: 'items' which takes care of children property naming . Your solution doesn't work even if items are added on the store initialization (uncomment root:data), which works perfectly without otherwise.